# Как организовать ввод целочисленных данных (от 1 до n) в одной строке через пробел?

Tags: c++

Для двух переменных: `cin >> x >> y;`. Для 3-ох: `cin >> x >> y >> z`. Неизвестно, сколько значений будут передаваться, а нужно, чтобы все значения обработались.

Comment: Цикл простой.
Не особо ясна суть вашего вопроса. 

Comment: Первое, что пришло в голову: считываем строку чисел, потом разбиваем эту строку на слова-числа и преобразовываем каждое "слово" в int.

Comment: как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем строки по одной. Для каждой делаем массив, заполняем его числами из строки, используя **strtol()**. Обрабатываем числа в массиве.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <errno.h>

int *
get_linarr (char *buf, int *nn)
{
  *nn = 0;
  if (!buf || !*buf)
    return NULL;
  int *arr = calloc(sizeof(int),strlen(buf)),
    n = 0;
  char *s = buf, *p;

  for (;;n++) {
    int x = strtol(s,&p,10);
    if (s == p) {
      if (*nn = n)
          arr = realloc(arr,n*sizeof(int));
      else {
          free(arr);
          arr = NULL;
      }
      return arr;
    }
    arr[n] = x;
    s = p;
  }

}

main ()
{
  char buf[1024];

  while (fgets(buf,1024,stdin)) {
    int n, *arr = get_linarr(buf,&n);
    if (n) {
      printf ("%d int numbers in line returns in array\n",n);
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          printf ("Processing %d number %d\n",i,arr[i]);
      free(arr);
    } else
      printf ("no numbers in line\n");
  }

}
```

Годиться ?

Answer (score 1):

Добавляет в список числа, пока ввод не завершен.

```
 list<int> numbers;
 int number;

 while (cin.good()) {
     cin >> number;
     numbers.push_back(number);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[25];
    for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не то